# Avoid some characteres (~) in Angular build URL

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, lazy-loading

I generate my app with Angular cli but I have noticed that some files (seem to have to do with lazy load) are generated with the '~' character, for example:

```
default~pages-admin-pages-admin-module-ngfactory~pages-user-pages-user-module-ngfactory.js
```

Looks like this files have to be with the Lazy load strategy, and I'm traying to avoid this, because this symbol make problems in some environments, but I don't know or where I can say it to angular-cli

Comment: Try running `ng build --aot --prod --output-hashing=none`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Owen Kelvin I found the solution with the --prod flag.

Maybe it's obvious, but I have a costumization environment with propierty

```
production: true
```

I thought it was the same, but not, it's necesary the flag to do the trick!